# Can this be solved with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to define some TypeScript-types so that the function *func1* can be invoked like this:

```
func1<G3>("propOfG3", { propOfG1:"test" } )
```

For this I have started with some type definitions. I put two questionmarks (??) at the part that I don't know how to define:

```
type G1 = {
    propOfG1:string
}

type G2<A> = {}

type G3 = {
    propOfG3: G2<G1>
}

function func1<T>(name: keyof T, o: ?? ) {}
```

The second parameter *o* of the function should be of type G1 (in this case) because G1 is the generic parameter of *propOfG3*'s type.

Can someone please help me to figure out how this can be defined?

EDIT: Here is an example of usage:

```
type Person = {
    surname:string
}

type Store<T> = {}

type Stores = {
    people : Store<Person>
}

function save<TStore>(name: keyof TStore, o:?? ) {}

//  call:

save<Stores>("people", { surname:"Laffer" })
```

Comment: G2 type makes no sense in this example, can you show some code where it is useful?

Comment: @MarekAugustyn I added an exemple now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you are able to do it as simply as you've stated.

The closest I believe you can get is as follows:

```
type Person = {
    surname:string
}

type Store<Person> = {}

type Stores = {
    people : Store<Person>
}

function save<TStores extends { [K in keyof TStores]: Store<T> }, T>(name: keyof TStores, o: T) {}

save<Stores, Person>("people", { surname:"Laffer" })
```